# Identificar se um link aponta para uma imagem, e adicionar uma class

Tags: javascript

Numa página, existem links que apontam para imagens.

`<a class="native-class" href="http://localhost/test/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/7-3.jpg"></a>`

Estou ciente de que poderia adicionar outra classe utilizando a classe `native-class` mas o que eu quero fazer é adicionar outra classe nesse link especifico caso o href seja uma imagem. `.png, jpg, gif` etc.

Comment: Fiz uma resposta mas fiquei na dúvida. O que quer dizer com "link específico"?

Comment: @dvd **esse é o comentário que eu estava escrevendo quando você removeu a resposta** rsrsr.


Sim, é uma solução elegantíssima! Mas de fato, o que eu gostaria é de utilizar como paramento apenas o valor **href** caso seja ['jpg','png','gif','svg'], é porque essa classe `native-classe` não existirá sempre, só a coloquei para exemplificar.

Comment: @dvd Quero que caso um link possua no href o endereço para uma imagem, adicionar uma classe.

Comment: @dvd sua resposta estava certa e resolvia o problema caso eu fosse utilizar a classe `native-classe`. A base para colocar a classe deve ser sempre o valor do href.

Comment: Restaurei a resposta editada

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pode fazer desta forma, percorrendo todos os links:

```js
var links = document.querySelectorAll("a");

for(var x=0; x<links.length; x++){
   
   if(links[x]
   .href // pego o valor do href
   .split(".") // quebro o valor
   .pop() // pego a extensão
   .match(/jpg|gif|png/)) // comparo
   links[x].classList.add("nova-class"); // adiciono a classe
   
}
```

```html
<a class="native-class" href="http://localhost/test/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/7-3.jpg">Link 1</a>
<a class="native-class" href="http://localhost/test/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/7-3.tiff">Link 2</a>
```

> Separe os *nomes da extensões* desejadas na regex do `match` por uma barra
>   vertical `|`.

Answer (score 0):

Um "pitaco" aqui, acho mais sucinto:

```js
document.querySelectorAll('a').forEach(link => {
    if ( /\.(jpg|png|gif)/g.test(link.href) ) {
        link.classList.add('nova-classe')
    }
    // mostrar
    console.log(link.classList.toString())
})
```

```html
<a class="native-class" href="http://localhost/test/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/7-3.jpg">jpg</a>
<a class="native-class" href="http://localhost/test/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/7-3.png">png</a>
<a class="native-class" href="http://localhost/test/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/7-3.gif">gif</a>
<a class="native-class" href="http://localhost/test/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/7-3.webp">webp</a>
<a class="native-class" href="http://localhost/test/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/7-3.svg">svg</a>
```